# Retrieving data from coredata by it's date attribute

Tags: ios, swift

How can I find an item I added to the core data by it's date attribute?
Here is the code I have so far. I am using a predicate to filter the request. I want to get the data to then eventually update the text stored in that particular entry

```
       
var request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Object")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateOfObject == %i", datePicker.date as CVarArg)
request.predicate = predicate
request.fetchLimit = 1
        

do{
      let count = try context.count(for: request)
      print(count)

      if(count == 0){
                userText.text = ""
      }
      else{
            // A matched object is in the coredata
            let objectFetched = try! context.fetch(request)
            userText.text = (objectFetched[0]).objectText
               
          }
  }
```

I am adding to the coredata like this:

```
let newObject = Object(context: self.context)
newObject.dateOfObject = date

do{
        try self.context.save()
  } 
catch{
        print("not valid")
  }
```

I don't think this code is comparing the two dates properly in *NSPredicate(format: "dateOfObject == %i", datePickerr.date as CVarArg)*

I also get the error *NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance....*  for the:  context.count(for: request).

Answer (score 1):

`Date`is treated as object, the object specifier is `%@`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateOfObject == %@", datePicker.date as CVarArg)
```

Your code can be shortened

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Object>(entityName: "Object")
// or even more recommended 
// let request : NSFetchRequest<Object> = Object.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateOfObject == %@", datePicker.date as CVarArg)
request.fetchLimit = 1
        
do {        
     if let object = try context.fetch(request).first {
        userText.text = object.objectText   
     } else {
        userText.text = ""
     }
} catch { print(error) }
```

and please delete the redundant `object` prefixes and suffixes in the attribute names (`text` and `date` is sufficient). The entity clearly indicates that it's an `Object`